# Who are the people in the final file?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016

At the end of the movie, we see Amanda Waller handing a file with profiles of three people to

> Bruce Wayne,

who says he "likes to make friends."  After which it is implied that

> Bruce Wayne / Batman is going to find those people, and with their help, shut down Amanda Waller and the Suicide Squad.

So, who are the people from the file?

Comment: related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/who-are-the-other-three-superheroes-in-batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice/50907#50907

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file is supposed to be a list of all of the meta-humans that Waller knows of.

Bruce Wayne already knows about the existence of 3 meta-humans from the files he stole from Luthor in *Dawn of Justice* (Cyborg, Flash, and Aquaman), but he assumes that Waller knows more. So, he somehow convinces or coerces her into handing over her files on those people, and any others. Note that the second dossier of Arthur Curry, which is likely where Bruce learns how to track him down.

This scene is leading up to the *Justice League* movie, where Bruce tracks down these metas and convinces them to join him to fight crime. His last words to Waller are warning her that her attempts to use supervillains for her dirty work will put them in conflict with himself and his group of superheros.

Comment: I believe he either bailed her out of the Enchantress debacle and/or agreed to protect her in the future.

Comment: Aha.  I guess I would have recognized Arthur Curry and had a better idea of what was going on in that scene had I seen Dawn of Justice.  Thanks @DaveJohnson for the related link!